# Edit/Object mode texture different

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view

I'm having the exact same problem in this thread:

[Textures appearing different in Edit and Object mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10517/textures-appearing-different-in-edit-and-object-mode)

But my mesh does not have any modifiers at all. Anyone has any idea of what else could be doing this issue?

[image]

Comment: try adding more details to your question screenshots , blend file

Comment: Here it is. It's the exact same issue. http://imgur.com/MM8RgvL

Comment: it doesn't seem too much different you may have flipped or intersecting double faces,     remove doubles and recalculate normals

Comment: Didn't work. The face keeps changing. Should I upload the blender file?

Comment: Okay, I fixed this in a kinda unorthodox way. Simply deleted the face and extruded a new one. Now it seems to work. I'm still new to this texturing thing, been banging my head on this specific work for a few days.Thanks anyway!